# How set a fixed cluster port for nodePort service in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, service-node-port-range

How can I set a fix cluster port for a nodePort service. I need to validate the incoming port inside the pod, hence required the same port to be forwarded to the pod when message reached inside the currently it picks a random port and node ip to send the packet into pod from the service.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a fixed port for the nodeport when you define it:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

> If you want a specific port number, you can specify a value in the nodePort field. The control plane will either allocate you that port or report that the API transaction failed. This means that you need to take care of possible port collisions yourself. You also have to use a valid port number, one that’s inside the range configured for NodePort use.

Comment: My query is not about the nodePort, my question is basically the cluster Port. The Port the will be seen in the incoming message  inside the POD.

Comment: You should be able to specify the same nodePort and targetPort value for the service, so the node would open the nodePort, and forward the traffic to the same numbered port of the pod. Didn't try this myself though.